# How to I set up nfs using the Drobo Unfsd app?

Tags: nfs, drobo, droboshare

How do I set up my nfs on my Drobo FS so that I can connect to it from my Mac using the NFS protocol?

I have downloaded and installed Unfsd program from the [DroboApps page](http://www.drobo.com/droboapps/apps-for-drobofs.php). My exports file looks like this:

```
/mnt/DroboFS/Shares 192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0(rw,no_root_squash)
```

I try to connect to the share by hitting Ctrl+K in Finder and the using

```
nfs://drobo-fs.local/Shares
```

as server address. But when I click Connect all that happens is that the Connect to Server window flashes shortly, and well, that's all.

I have tried removing the /Shares part, using /Public and casing drobo-fs.local as Drobo-FS.local, but it's all with the same result. I have also tried using `/mnt/DroboFS/Shares *(rw,no_root_squash)` in the exports file. I restart the service using the command ./service.sh restart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just set up the same system. The answer is you have to provide the entire path, i.e. in "Connect To Server", use this:

```
nfs://drobo-fs.local/mnt/DroboFS/Shares/
```

Also, since the DroboFS isn't too careful with permissions (it does all of its work as root), you may want to use the very insecure

```
/mnt/DroboFS/Shares 10.0.0.0/8(ro,all_squash,anonuid=0,anongid=0)
```

This will cause everyone to look like root to the NFS server, which is rather how things look to the DroboFS.

Comment: "since the DroboFS isn't too careful with permissions (it does all of its work as root)..." Yikes! I was thinking about getting a Drobo, but I think you may have convinced me not to.